# How to parse a JSON file and lookup for a specific key and then return value?

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

JSON newbie here. I am trying to do a lookup for a specific value from a JSON file. Basically, I have a search box where user can select a "name" (see jSON) from the existing list of "name"(s) from an auto-complete drop-down. The idea is to return the corresponding "url" value of the entered "name".

JSON (docs.json):

```
[
    { "tag": "Tutorial", "name": "Using Cloud", "url": "http://example.com/staff/doc/platform_training/index.html" },
    { "tag": "Tutorial", "name": "Help Tutorials", "url": "http://example.com/mason/staff/doc/tutorials/help/agent.html" },
    { "tag": "Tutorial", "name": "Big Stuff", "url": "http://example.com/mason/staff/doc/tutorials/orientation.html" }

]
```

jQuery:

```
        $('.livesearch').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
        searchTerm = $("#search").val();
        // return the "url" based on the "searchTerm", which is basically the "name" key in the JSON file
        }

        });


        function readJSON(searchTerm) {
            $.getJSON( "json/docs.json", function( data ) {
                $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                    // 
                });
            });

        }
```

HTML:

```
<input class="livesearch" type="text" placeholder="Enter your search terms here" id="search" />
```

Answer (score 1):

After you set your `searchTerm`, call the `readJSON(searchTerm)` function, then in your callback do:

```
var url = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].hasOwnProperty("name")) {
        if (data[i].name == searchTerm) {
            url = data[i].name;
            break; //bye bye for loop
        }
    }
}

//do stuff
```